# Desirability of chaining an LCG in an authentication scheme

Tags: block-cipher, authentication, mac, authenticated-encryption, modes-of-operation

Suppose that:

- $E(k, x)$ is the encryption of data block $x$ with key $k$ using a block cipher.
- $L_{Key}$ is the key size of the block cipher in bits.
- $L_{Block}$ is the block size of the block cipher in bits.
- $F(x) = (a \cdot x + c) \mbox{ mod } m$, so it's a linear congruential generator.
- $m = 2^{L_{Block}}$ is the modulus to be used in $F$.
- $a$ and $c$ are such that $F$ has a full period.
- $K \leftarrow \{0, 1\}^{L_{Key}}$ is a secret key to be used with the block cipher.
- $J \leftarrow \{0, 1\}^{L_{Block}}$ is a value that is derived in some way from $K$, perhaps through using $E$ and a constant.
- $T \leftarrow \{0, 1\}^{L_{Block}}$ is an authentication tag.
- $i$ is a one-based index.
- $x_{i} \leftarrow \{0, 1\}^{L_{Block}}$ is the $i$<sup>th</sup> block in a stream of data to be verified.
- $s$ is the number of data blocks.
- $y_{i} = x_{i} \oplus J$.
- $t$ is an intermediate value that is calculated prior to $T$. It is first calculated as $t = F(y_{1})$, after which it is recalculated as $t = F(y_{i} \oplus t)$.
- $T = E(K, t)$.

Seems secure enough to me (I know that isn't a good assurance, but I know jack about cryptanalysis), assuming the block cipher is secure. Block ciphers typically invoke one or more modular addition operations, so I don't think computing $b \boxplus c$ (where $b = m \cdot x$) is going to be a slow operation. I have no clue as to how much slower the multiplication would be. Would it be too slow to make for a good authentication mode?

**Update #1**: If $a = 65537$, then computing $a \cdot x$ would only require shifting $x$ to the left by four places and then adding $x$ to the result, which would be much faster than if $a$ had a larger Hamming weight. How much of an improvement in speed would this provide over GCM?

Comment: Use $m = 2^{130 - 5}$, use $t = F(y_i + t)$ instead of $t = F(y_i \oplus t)$, and set $c = 0$, and you'll have a state-of-the-art MAC built out of Poly1305.  Use $\operatorname{GF}(2^{128})$ instead of $\mathbb Z/(2^{130} - 5)\mathbb Z$, and you'll have a state-of-the-art MAC built out of GHASH or POLYVAL like AES-GCM-SIV uses it.

Comment: That's $2^{130} - 5$ above—misplaced a closing brace!

Comment: @SqueamishOssifrage That's nice, but I was hoping for commentary on the scheme I proposed. What is the POLYVAL function? I have not seen it before.

Comment: POLYVAL is the same as GHASH but with different bit order, and in the proposed AES-GCM-SIV AEAD.  As for analyzing the specific scheme: (a) that's why I posted a comment instead of a reply, (b) this isn't really the venue for requests for analysis of specific new cryptosystems, and (c) simplified versions of your scheme, with $c = 0$ and only tiny variations, are already widespread.

Comment: My comment above was apparently premised on $a$ and $c$ being secret and chosen uniformly at random, not being standard parameters.

Answer (score 1):

> Would it be too slow to make for a good authentication mode?

No, it would be too insecure for a good authentication mode.

In particular, given any message $M$ that's at least two blocks long, it's trivial to find a second message $M' \ne M$ that has the same tag (no matter what the key is); and hence one could be substituted for the other without detection.

Comment: How does it differ from GCM or Chaskey to make that the case? Remember, the tag is encrypted at the end.

Comment: @Melab: there's quite a few differences between what you have and GCM (more properly, GHASH); GHASH works in the field $GF(2^{128})$ using a secret multiplier; you're working in the ring $\mathbb{Z}/2^{L}$ (mostly, you xor in the message) using a public multiplier and a secret initial value.  As for Chaskey, well, about the only thing that's similar between your approach and Chaskey's is the reliance on a secret initial value.  I suspect the moral is "don't blindly tweak crypto if you don't know what you're doing"

Comment: @Melab: typo: I meant GMAC, not GHASH in the previous comment...

Comment: Using a secret initial value doesn't make it secure?

Comment: @Melab: no, a secret initial value doesn't make it secure; it doesn't change how it processes related messages...

Comment: What if the offset was secret?