# How does Poly1305 use $2^{130}-5$?

Tags: poly1305

How is the number $2^{130}-5$ used in Poly1305? It operates on blocks that are 128 bits long, but the number has 130 bits. I don't understand how it is used. [This](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/51590/desirability-of-chaining-an-lcg-in-an-authentication-scheme#comment113945_51590) comment makes me think it uses integer arithmetic.

Comment: The complete details of the format are given in the [paper](https://cr.yp.to/papers.html#poly1305) on p. 4, and the one-line Poly1305 formula is then given on p. 5.  I recommend reading that—you don't have to follow the whole paper to understand those two pages.  The even briefer summary is that the bit string message is padded and broken into 129-bit chunks that are interpreted as unsigned little-endian integers.

Comment: There's also [this explanation](http://loup-vaillant.fr/tutorials/poly1305-design) if you're less familiar with the background.